# News+ Activities disappear

Tags: news.app

I rearranged the Sharing Activities in News on my iPad and when Done, the News-specific items stopped showing in the Activities.  I reproduced in News on my iPhone.

Steps: Open News, go to News+, on an article touch the Sharing icon.  When the Sharing pane shows, scroll Right to More...  Rearrange the items to put "Save" as the first item.  Tap Done.

All News Activities are gone!  Share, Love, Dislike…

I deleted the app and downloaded it…no luck.

Any ideas on how to reset the Activies under Sharing for this app?

Comment: Firstly, welcome to Ask Different! :)  I hope you come to find this site has a lot to offer! In case you haven't already, it's worth taking the time to read the [tour](https://apple.stackexchange.com/tour). All the best with your question!